# Exchange 2007 migration to Office 365

Tags: exchange-2007, microsoft-office-365

I have just recently migrated a domain over to Office 365 from Exchange 2007 but all other domains that are on the exchange 2007 cannot send mail to the domain under Office 365 on the exchange 2007 I have removed the domain from the accepted domain but mail is still not delivering does anybody have any ideas?

This is the bounceback I received before I removed from accepted domains.

```
Delivery has failed to these recipients or distribution lists:

Leah Bray<mailto:leah.bray@london-belgravia.com>

The recipient’s e-mail address was not found in the recipient’s e-mail system. Microsoft Exchange will not try to redeliver this message for you. Please check the e-mail address and try resending this message, or provide the following diagnostic text to your system administrator.

Sent by Microsoft Exchange Server 2007


Diagnostic information for administrators:

Generating server: AVANTAMX07.avanta.co.uk
leah.bray@london-belgravia.com
#550 5.1.1 RESOLVER.ADR.RecipNotFound; not found ##

Original message headers:
Received: from AVANTAMXBE.avanta.co.uk ([::1]) by AVANTAMX07.avanta.co.uk
([::1]) with mapi; Mon, 21 Jul 2014 12:55:39 +0100
Content-Type: application/ms-tnef; name=”winmail.dat”
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
From:   Dean Carney <Dean.Carney@avanta.co.uk>
To: Leah Bray <leah.bray@london-belgravia.com>
Date:   Mon, 21 Jul 2014 12:55:37 +0100
Subject:    Test
    Thread-Topic: Test
    Thread-Index: Ac+k2q+9WnAsgceASBOBIBIYQ6u11w==
    Message-ID: <26EE075CEBB5124FB7441B5B29667F2A0DEF09B46A@AVANTAMXBE.avanta.co.uk>
    Accept-Language: en-US, en-GB
    Content-Language: en-US
    X-MS-Has-Attach: yes
    X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: <26EE075CEBB5124FB7441B5B29667F2A0DEF09B46A@AVANTAMXBE.avanta.co.uk>
    MIME-Version: 1.0
```

After I removed the domain from the accepted domains list. Mail looks like it goes through as I do not receive a bounceback but once i check the Office 365 account no mail has come through.

Also i am now receiving the below Bounceback

```
This is the mail system at host titan.avanta.co.uk.
I’m sorry to have to inform you that your message could not be delivered to one or more recipients. It’s attached below.
For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.
If you do so, please include this problem report. You can delete your own text from the attached returned message.
The mail system
<leah.bray@london-belgravia.com>: host said:
550 5.7.1 Unable to relay (in reply to RCPT TO command)
```

Comment: We need way more info on that. What error messages? How's the setup exactly? and so on. See the help for information on how to ask good questions

Comment: What migration method have you used? I'm thinking you may be going for a hybrid scenario, but would be very helpful to know which route you've taken before we can help further

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information you've provided, my only thought would be that it could be the user on the Exchange box that you've left behind to represent the moved user isn't stamped with the correct target address. See here for more information: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2685437